# JSON to JavaScript, SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but I really don´t get it.

I am creating a site in MVC, and I'm creating a JSON string from my model. I then want to pass it as argument to a JavaScript function that uses it to plot a graph.

Here is were I create the JSON string. This indeed creates a valid JSON string, I checked it at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var weightsAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(Enumerable.Select(Model, weight =>
        new
        {
            date = weight.Date,
            value = weight.Value
        }));
}
```

Further down I create a JavaScript variable from it and pass it into the JavaScript function:

```
var jsonStringToGraph = @weightsAsJsonString;    
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(jsonstring));
```

When I run this, the console prints 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token &' at the line were I declare `jsonStringToGraph`. I googled around and concluded that I should put ' ' around `@weightsAsJsonString`, so I do that.

Anyway, in my drawVisualization, I do this:

```
function drawVisualization(teststring) {
    .......
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(teststring);
```

This gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token & Index:1`
I know that the code at the bottom is what is causing the exception, but I do not understand why. Do anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Edit: This is the weightsAsJsonString

```
[{"date":"\/Date(1434492000000)\/","value":100.2},{"date":"\/Date(1434578400000)\/","value":99.2},{"date":"\/Date(1434664800000)\/","value":101.2},{"date":"\/Date(1434751200000)\/","value":98.2},{"date":"\/Date(1434837600000)\/","value":97.2},{"date":"\/Date(1434924000000)\/","value":96.2},{"date":"\/Date(1435010400000)\/","value":95.2},{"date":"\/Date(1435096800000)\/","value":94.2}]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `jsonStringToGraph` looks like? I'd have to actually see the syntax in order to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I can´t set the breakpoint there, but I added the variable that it reads from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is trying to inject content via Razor into JavaScript. By default `@` will HTML-encode your content, which doesn't work in the context of JavaScript.

`@Html.Raw(weightsAsJsonString)` will work better, and then your JS will have a JavaScript object, so there's no need for the `JSON.parse` later on.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, I will check it now

Comment: so you mean that I do like this:
`    var objects = @Html.Raw(weightsAsJsonString);
   
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(objects));`?

Comment: Yep, but you'll have to remove that `JSON.parse` from `drawVisualization` since it's not JSON but a JavaScript object at that point.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var jsonStringToGraph = @weightsAsJsonString;` you are actually defining a JSON ***object*** and not a JSON ***string***.

Hence when you do `JSON.parse(teststring);` you are trying to parse an object instead of a string.

Either put apostrophes around the first declaration `var jsonStringToGraph = '@weightsAsJsonString';` or simply do not try to parse it again.

Comment: I did put apostrphes around my first declaration, this is what happends:
When I run `var objects = JSON.parse(teststring);` in the JavaScript function, in throws the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token & Index:1`. Thanks for helping