# MVC List to jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having an issue pushing a list from my C# model in razor to jquery to play with!

So assume my List is working well and I am able to see the data in razor *(Because I can)*

I then have the following:

```
@using Models.DatabaseModel;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@{
    Person _Person = ViewBag._Person;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        operations = _Person
    });
 }
```

And then at the bottom I have a javascript loading as so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            StoreUserInfo("@json");
        });
    </script>
```

The following calls the javascript correctly, but the string that is passed through to the javascript is full of html characters

An example: **"{"operations":{"PersonID":"8"}}"**

My jquery is as follows:

```
function StoreUserInfo(UserObject)
{
    var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(UserObject);
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

    } else {

    }

}
```

Which errors with the Syntax Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1

The theory behind this is my C# list pushes a heap of data that I want to store in local storage, I am open to a better method to do this if anyone has it or solutions to my syntax issue I am having.

Comment: Probably `UserObject` is already contains a JSON object, where `$.parseJSON` calls `toString` method which reveals `&` sign at first place (possibly by `&quot;`) causing the problem. Can you provide sample of passed string to JS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this approach. I use this when it's necessary to access my model in javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var list = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { operations = ViewBag._Person }))';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            StoreUserInfo(list);
        });
        function StoreUserInfo(UserObject)
        {
            var jsonobj = JSON.parse(UserObject);
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

            } else {

            }    
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `var jsonobj = JSON.parse(UserObject);` won't be needed then I guess, as UserObject is already in Json format.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the tip on the HTML Raw, my final solution was changing the javascript call to the following. StoreUserInfo(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(_Person))); and then dropping the json ser in the javascript, the object came through perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `StoreUserInfo` call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     StoreUserInfo("@json");
});
```

The `@json` part actually defining a JSON object instead of JSON string, since `@` sign actually encodes your JSON string to encoded HTML format like this:

```
&quot;{&quot;operations&quot;:{&quot;PersonID&quot;:&quot;8&quot;}}&quot;
```

Since it tries to parse `&` sign in JS object, it throws syntax error.

Instead, use `Html.Raw` with `Json.Encode` method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     StoreUserInfo("@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(json))");
});
```

**NB:** It is better to parse JSON string through a viewmodel property instead generating JSON string inside view like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        StoreUserInfo("@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.JsonString)");
    });
</script>
```

Note that in version 3.0 [`$.parseJSON` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/), you can change/remove it since it may be unnecessary to parse already-made JS object.

```
function StoreUserInfo(UserObject)
{
    // parsing JSON string may be unnecessary here
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Related issues:

[JSON to JavaScript, SyntaxError: Unexpected token &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548856/json-to-javascript-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194442/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json)

Comment: Your answer was correct, but had to be fair and give it to the first! I am using MVC6 so the Json.Encode was Json.Serialize

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using `@Html.Raw`:

```
<script>
    var person = 
        @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
           new { Name = "Yoshi", Age = 32 }))
        alert(person.Name);
</script>
```